# Fetching "Pending" Users Related To Entry Within Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, users, plugins, entrymodel, usermodel

This works (but only obtains the active users):

```
// get entry
$entry = craft()->entries->getEntryById($entryId);

// get existing users in field
$entry->customUserField->ids();
```

So in attempting to get the non-active users I've switched to using the ElementCriteriaModel but have been unsuccessful:

```
// get entry
$entry = craft()->entries->getEntryById($entryId);

// get field model
$field = craft()->fields->getFieldByHandle('customUserField');

// get all users for entry+field
$getUsers = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::User);
$getUsers->relatedTo([
    'targetElement' => $entry,
    'field' => $field,
    'status' => null  // user status null
]);

$users = $getUsers->find();
```

I'm certain I'm doing something wrong within my relatedTo parameters. Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, spent hours trying to figure this out and came upon the answer within an hour after posting the question on Stack.

Here's the working code:

```
    // get entry
    $entry = craft()->entries->getEntryById($entryId);

    // get ALL users related to entry
    $users = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::User);
    $users->status = null;
    $users->relatedTo = [$entry];
    $userIds = $users->ids();
```